# Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a facebook app to get all the images my page is tagged in. It includes the following steps.

1 Get user access token with manage_pages,... permissions
2 Get the page access token from me/accounts endpoint 
3 Get the photos using me/photos/tagged endpoint using access token i got in step 2

Every thing is working fine when in choose application as "graph api explorer" in the graph api explorer.

But when I select my application. It does not show me the images by other people in which my page was tagged.

Is there Something I am missing? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs to authenticate the page access token with the "manage_pages" permission for this call to work. To obtain a page access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token from the admin user of the page and ask for the manage_pages permission from your app when the user authenticates (logs in with your app). This document goes into details on how you can implement the flow I described above : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already getting the page access token. Ok here is the thing. I have a page and  I want to run a contest for that page I am the admin of that page. I want people to post pictures on their wall and tag my page in their picture. at the end i want to get all the pictures my page is tagged in using graph api. Is there a way to do this ?. I have tried all the things. I created a app the i got the access token with all the permissions including manage_pages. then i got the page access toke using me/accounts endpoint. then using that access token me/photos/tagged. no luck.